# D'où vient la structure de « tel quel » ?

Tags: étymologie, locutions

Après m'être référé à quelques sites Web [[1](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/tel/77019/expression?q=tel+quel#16001969),[2](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1134964),[3](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2237466)], je comprends la définition de « tel(le)(s) quel(le)(s) ». Malgré cela, je ne saisis pas comment et ne m'imaginais pas que la juxtaposition de ces deux mots mène à ce sens. Du coup, je m'enquiers de la structure et l'intuition (et NON PAS de la signification). Voici un exemple de Jean Chrysostome :

> Pierre comprit et il se prit à pleurer; il pleura, il versa non pas des larmes **telles quelles**, mais des larmes amères, faisant de ces larmes l'eau d'un second baptême…

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait lieu de « crier » si une réponse vous déplaît. Donner un *downvote* ou laisser un commentaire à la réponse en question sont de meilleures manières d'aborder le problème que de mettre inopinément un passage de la question en majuscules.

Comment: @Kareen: Je vous remercie et conviens foncièrement de votre commentaire. En réalité, puisque j'avais déjà employé le gras pour insister sur **telles quelles**, j'avais en tête l'usage de couleur, mais qui est indisponible sur French MSE. Du coup, je n'ai brigué que plus de l'accent envers (et non pas de la signification) avec les majuscules, la seule dernière option.

Answer (score 1):

Le petit Robert indique :

Tel quel : *sans arrangement, sans modification* : laisser les choses telles qu'elles sont, en l'état.

Une façon de décoder la phrase :

> - ... il versa non pas des larmes telles qu'elles viennent normalement, mais des larmes amères ...

Une manière intuitive de lire la phrase :

- > ... il versa non pas des larmes naturelles, mais des larmes amères, ...

---

P.S. : Pour des recherches approfondies, consulter les portails tels le [*cnrtl*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/), le [*tlfi*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/) ou les sites mentionnés dans les réponses de ce forum : les sources que vous citez ne sont pas des références validées par l'Académie, l'Université ou les Centres de Recherche.

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question. Peux-tu préciser en quoi les ressources du cnrtl sont d'une grande aide ici ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai complété le P.S.

Comment: @cl-r: Merci de votre réponse. Après l'avoir laissé mûrir, je ne peux que subir et me renseigner à l'acception officielle et je n'en veux plus. Par conséquent, SVP, pourriez-vous désosser les deux mots ?

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que cette structure est un héritage direct du latin [*talis qualis*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talis_qualis).